# Put yfinance stock data into pandas dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, stock, yfinance

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

DataFrame:

| Ticker | Date |
| --- | --- |
| AAPL | 2022-11-22 |
| MSFT | 2022-11-22 |
| META | 2022-11-22 |

And I want to add a column that includes the stock price of each stock at that date like this:

| Ticker | Date | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 2022-11-22 | 147,47 |
| MSFT | 2022-11-22 | 243,71 |
| META | 2022-11-22 | 108,50 |

In the ideal situation, I would append each price for the Ticker[i] inside the for loop, so I can easily make an Except: "not available" command for the stocks that are not found.

What I have done so far is creating the following for loop, which let me to get all stock prices. However, I cannot find a way to merge/append/concatenate it to the dataframe. I currently have 2 separate dataframes, without a common column which makes it hard to merge.

```
for i in DataFrame.index:
    ticker = DataFrame.index['Ticker'][i]
    start_date = DataFrame.index['Date'][i]
    data1 = pd.DataFrame(yf.download(ticker, start_date, start_date))
```

Comment: when you create data dataframe add the Ticker name as a column as well, then you can merge on Ticker

Answer (score 0):

no loop is needed , not familiar with yf but nevertheless you can use apply :

```
df['price'] = df.apply(lambda x : yf.download(x.['ticker'], x.['start_date'], x.['start_date']))
```